# Get last cell in a column from an SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, load, save

Quite a specific question.
I'm making a program which detects files. When there's a new file with a specific name, it saves it to a server. This works fine. The problem is, one of the variables it saves is a unique number, which is supposed to increase for every file it uploads.
So the first file has the unique number 400, and the next file has unique numer 401 and so on.

I uploaded a test file to the server, so there's already a first file with unique number 400.
What I want now is that my next file should have the next number.
For that to happen, it has to get the the number from the last cell in the first column.
I found out that the SQL statement is SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EKG_Temp ORDER BY ekgmaaleid DESC.
I've outcommented the loadCMD which is the command containing the SQL statement.

The name of the table is EKG_Temp. The name of the column is ekgmaaleid, the type is a BigInt

**I'm interested in saving the last cell in column ekgmaaleid as a variable in my program for later use basically.**

```
    public void SaveFile(string fileName, byte[] BlobValue)
    {
        string fullPath = (folder + "/" + fileName);
        fileExtension = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 3);
        if (saveBool == true)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Irrelavant");
            SqlCommand SaveCmdTemporary = new SqlCommand("insert into EKG_Temp(ekgmaaleid,dato,borger_cprnr,raa_data,maaleformat_type) values(@ekgmaaleid,@dato,@borger_cprnr,@raa_data,@maaleformat_type)", con);
            //SqlCommand SaveCmdPermanent = new SqlCommand("insert into EKG_Temp(ekgmaaleid,dato,borger_cprnr,raa_data,maaleformat_type) values(@ekgmaaleid,@dato,@borger_cprnr,@raa_data,@maaleformat_type)", con);
            //SqlCommand LoadCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EKG_Temp ORDER BY ekgmaaleid DESC", con); //Husk at den faktisk skal vælge måleid ud fra EKG_Gemt i virkeligheden
            SqlParameter ekgmaaleidParam = new SqlParameter("@ekgmaaleid", SqlDbType.BigInt);
            SqlParameter datoParam = new SqlParameter("@dato", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            SqlParameter borger_cprnrParam = new SqlParameter("@borger_cprnr", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            SqlParameter raa_dataParam = new SqlParameter("@raa_data", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
            SqlParameter maaleformat_typeParam = new SqlParameter("@maaleformat_type", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
            SqlParameter loadMaaleIDParam = new SqlParameter("@ekgmaaleid", SqlDbType.BigInt);
            con.Open();
            SaveCmdTemporary.Parameters.Add(ekgmaaleidParam);
            SaveCmdTemporary.Parameters.Add(datoParam);
            SaveCmdTemporary.Parameters.Add(borger_cprnrParam);
            SaveCmdTemporary.Parameters.Add(raa_dataParam);
            SaveCmdTemporary.Parameters.Add(maaleformat_typeParam);
            //LoadCmd.Parameters.Add(loadMaaleIDParam);
            datoParam.Value = dato;
            borger_cprnrParam.Value = cpr;
            raa_dataParam.Value = BlobValue; //Kommer fra metoden FileCreated.
            maaleformat_typeParam.Value = fileExtension;
            try
            {
                SaveCmdTemporary.Connection.Open();
                SaveCmdTemporary.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("File saved to database.", "BLOB Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Save Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                SaveCmdTemporary.Connection.Close();
                saveBool = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Here's a picture of the database and what I wish it to do.

[image: Database]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to look for identity specification on your table field : it will increase the number for you... Then if you actually need the last id generated from your code, it's quite simple to get it. Note that if you intent to serve file to users, you should at least have another identifier so that no one can get a file he's not intended to get just by user another number. Note also it is always best to store user uploaded files outside of the webroot.

Comment: Observation: the connection and command are `IDisposable`; using `using` would save a lot of risk

Comment: so what exactly is your problem? you already mentioned the SELECT TOP 1 statement you have to execute to get the latest number ... and then you can use it in your INSERT statement ... not nice but should work ...

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn I want something like;
ekgmaaleidParam.Value= TheValueILoadedFromLoadCmd + 1;
I don't know exactly how to extract that value from the command LoadCmd.

Comment: try: int id = (int)LoadCmd.ExecuteScalar();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to create the table with an `identity` column; then the *database* will generate this value for you. The value of the identity value *inserted immediately before* is available via `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or `@@IDENTITY` (the former is preferred - especially if there are triggers; the latter works on more database versions, but has edge-cases).

On multi-user databases, this also avoids issues of race conditions (where obviously only one connection knows about the most recent inserts). You simply change the `insert` command to *not specify* the `identity` column (the database will supply this value; you don't have to).

Comment: I'll try not to be flippant; While I do appreciate your answer, and it is probably correct, I unfortunately cannot use it - because I am not allowed to make any more columns. (This is an assignment)

Comment: You don't have to add any more columns, just set Identity Specification for ekgmaaleid to Yes, provided it is an integer or UUID type. As Marc says, trying to set this value yourself in this way means your app is not multi-user safe. Incidentally, there is a better option than SCOPE_IDENTITY & @@IDENTITY, which is to use the OUTPUT clause of the insert statement. As in INSERT INTO ... OUTPUT INSERTED.ekgmaaleid VALUES....